# How to cache one particular reverse-proxied route in NGINX?

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I am using nginx as reverse proxy and here is a snippet from my config which routes anything under `/api` calls to an internal API server:

```
  # API server
  location /api {
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
      return 204;
    }

    # Proxy settings
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://my.api-server.com

    # Error handlers
    error_page 504 /errors/504.json;

    # CORS headers
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Allow' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referrer, User-Agent, Authorization, X-Impersonate-As, X-Request-Context' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization, X-Request-Id, X-Server-Time' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 3628800;
  }
```

But now I want to allow a rule to cache one particular reverse-proxy route (say `/api/foo/bar` with TTL = 30mins) and I tried this:

```
  location /api {
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
      return 204;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* /api/foo/bar) {
      proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 30m;
      add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }
    ....
```

But, that does not work. What is the best way to do this?

EDIT:

Full server config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types text/plain
               text/xml
               text/css
               text/javascript
               application/json
               application/javascript
               application/x-javascript
               application/ecmascript
               application/xml
               application/rss+xml
               application/atom+xml
               application/rdf+xml
               application/xml+rss
               application/xhtml+xml
               application/x-font-ttf
               application/x-font-opentype
               application/vnd.ms-fontobject
               image/svg+xml
               image/x-icon
               application/atom_xml;

    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

    keepalive_timeout           60;
    proxy_connect_timeout       60;
    proxy_send_timeout          60;
    proxy_read_timeout          60;
    send_timeout                60;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    proxy_cache_path /dev/shm levels=1:2 keys_zone=mcache:16m inactive=600s max_size=512m;
    proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
    proxy_cache_key "$request_method$host$request_uri";
    proxy_cache_use_stale timeout updating;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name my.company.com;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

  server {
    listen 443 http2 default_server ssl;

    server_name my.company.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;
    ssl on;

    # API server
    location /api {
      if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        return 204;
      }

      # Proxy settings
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://internal-api-server;

      # Error handlers
      error_page 504 /errors/504.json;

    if ($request_uri ~* /api/foo/bar) {
      proxy_cache_bypass 0;
      proxy_no_cache     0;
      proxy_cache        mcache; # mcache=RAM
      proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302  30m;
      proxy_cache_valid 403 404      5m;
      proxy_cache_lock   on;
      proxy_cache_use_stale timeout updating;
      add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }

      # CORS headers
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
      add_header 'Allow' '*' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referrer, User-Agent, Authorization, X-Impersonate-As, X-Request-Context' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization, X-Info-Resources' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 3628800 always;
    }

    location ^~ /errors/ {
      internal;
      root /etc/nginx/static-files/;
    }

    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log off;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @peixotorms: I put the full `cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in my EDIT above

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to look into:

1. Nginx only caches GET and HEAD requests by default.
2. Nginx won't cache any POST or anything with COOKIES on it by default.

To force cache when using cookies:

```
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
```

To cache with other request methods (choose your own):

```
proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE PATCH OPTIONS;
```

===

EDIT:

Try these settings:

On /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
proxy_cache_path /dev/shm levels=1:2 keys_zone=mcache:16m inactive=600s max_size=512m;
proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD;
proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
proxy_cache_key "$request_method$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache_use_stale timeout updating;
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
```

On your location block:

```
location /api/foo/bar {
    proxy_cache_bypass 0;
    proxy_no_cache     0;
    proxy_cache        mcache; # mcache=RAM
    proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302  30m;
    proxy_cache_valid 403 404      5m;
    proxy_cache_lock   on;
    proxy_cache_use_stale timeout updating;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
}
```

Make sure Nginx is reloaded (or stop + start)

```
service nginx reload
```

Test with curl:

```
curl -X GET -I https://yoururl
```

Comment: Thanks but this is a simple GET and there are no cookies involved (yet). I am trying from `curl` in command line.

Comment: Please post your full nginx.conf as well as relevant configuration such as location blocks and included conf files. What are the headers returned by curl?

Comment: I added the full server block. The curl for `/api/foo/bar` only returns the proxied headers (so I know it is going into the IF block) while other APIs do return the rest of the Access-Control headers too.

Comment: while the server block is useful. it doesn't tell me for instance, if you have a `proxy_cache_path` or a `proxy_cache_key` (among other things) set on the server. Please post your `nginx.conf` file.

Comment: It is complainging that `nginx: [emerg] "proxy_cache_bypass" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:107` - it does not like any of the `proxy_pass` settings in the if block

Comment: Just replace your `if` by another location block `location /api/foo/bar {` like in my answer.

Comment: But then it would not fall through and capture rest of the settings from the parent e.g. I have to copy in large swathes of settings from outside to inside e.g. about the rest of the `addHeaders`, `errorPage` etc etc. Is there a reusable way using an `if` block rather than a `location` block which would force me to repeat whats in the non-cache section...

Comment: The order matters, so you just have to move location `/api/foo/bar {` further up (or as a first rule). Nginx will try to parse those location blocks in order and stop on the first match.

Comment: I understand that but how do I share a lot of common settings between 2 location blocks? In this case, besides the cache, everything else is same - don't want to copy paste.

Comment: Put the common settings in another conf file and then include that file inside your location blocks.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you specify the proxy_cache_path (or is that just not included in your example?)